# Eclipse product does not recognize fragment (uncompressed)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-fragment

I have an eclipse PRODUCT that has plugins and fragments:

**Plugin A** (PRODUCT MAIN Plugin)
*Exported Plugins* (eclipse DROPINS folder):
**Plugin B** (Dependency of **Plugin A**)
**Fragment A** (HOST=**Plugin B**) - **UNCOMPRESSED**=resources
**Fragment B** (HOST=**Plugin B**)

**Problem**:
PRODUCT dependencies gives error, because Fragment A IS NOT recognized! 
It must be COMPRESSED in JAR format to be recognized!

I don't really understand this, because, if Plugin B is the PRODUCT MAIN plugin, any UNCOMPRESSED fragments are recognized:

**Plugin B** (PRODUCT MAIN Plugin)
**Fragment A** (HOST=**Plugin B**) - **UNCOMPRESSED**=resources
**Fragment B** (HOST=**Plugin B**)

PRODUCT has no errors and exports fine, as expected!

So why can't **Plugin B** be used as a dependency of another plugin?

Any solutions?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  For example, the tags `[eclipse]` and `[fragment]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[eclipse-fragment]` tag.  Tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They were useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a **CLEAN** command (ECLIPSE.exe -clean) the fragments are recognized.

It seems that eclipse needs to rebuild some internal configuration every time a "plugin" shifts from JAR to DIR (or the other way around...)